# Xpath select two different nodes without certain node

Tags: xml, xpath

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I have the following XML structure:

```
  <fruit>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <species>Tree</species>
    <features>
      <from>Reineta</from>
      <into>Golden</into>
    </features>
  </fruit>

  <fruit>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Orange</name>
    <species>Tree</species>
    <features>
      <from>Citric</from>
      <into>Mediterranean</into>
    </features>
  </fruit>

  <fruit>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Peach</name>
    <species>Tree</species>
    <features>
      <from>Golden</from>
    </features>
  </fruit>
```

How can I get the `<name>` and `<features>` of those fruit nodes **whose doesn't contain the features/into** nodes?

I tried this:

```
//fruit/features[from][not(into)]
```

I only can get the `<features>`, but how can I get the `<name>` too, in the same query?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is XPath 1.0, then your best bet is to use union operator (`|`) to combine result from XPath that return `features` and another XPath that return `name` :

```
//fruit/features[from and not(into)] | //fruit[features[from and not(into)]]/name
```

In higher version of XPath, you can use FLWOR expression to do the following (assuming `fruit` element can contains only one `features` element at a time) :

```
for $fruit in //fruit[features[from and not(into)]]
return ($fruit/name,$fruit/features)
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/Ra6R2r27i)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you for the demo link/button.